# Can't rewrite and redirect a url properly in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am trying to make the url(s) in my website user friendly, but it seems like .htaccess rewrite commands are not taken into consideration at all by the server.

The project is in the `localhost` and it is named `ecommerce`.
I want to "convert" this url: `localhost/ecommerce/product?name=abc`
to `localhost/ecommerce/product/abc`.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

##hide /index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\index [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]


##HERE IS THE IMPORTANT PART
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /product\.php\?name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /product/%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/]+)/?$ /product.php?name=$1 [L]
```

When I visit `localhost/ecommerce/product?name=abc` the url remains as it is and when I visit `localhost/ecommerce/product/abc` I get `500 Internal Server Error`.

I thought there was a problem with xampp httpd.conf, so I changed

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and it still doesn't work!

Removing the part where I hide the .php extension from .htaccess also doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Is this .htaccess located inside `/ecommerce/` directory?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it is inside `localhost/ecommerce/`

Comment: change `RewriteBase /` with `RewriteBase /ecommerce`

Comment: @Gulshan Thanks, but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this inside `/ecommerce/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ecommerce/

##HERE IS THE IMPORTANT PART
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ product/%1/? [L,R=301]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: After some "interventions" I did, it works like a charm! Thank you. I had to use `<base href="/ecommerce/">` in my .PHP files, so CSS could load successfully. It seems like you just changed the order of the commands(and some other changes of course). Can you explain why the ordering makes such a difference?

Comment: I believe biggest problem was having `RewriteBase /` and `/product/...` in target URIs in your rules. Ordering of rules also matter by keeping specific rules first and generic one later.